# Docker Rails Production Logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, docker, config, production

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project that exists in a Docker image and I am trying to log to an output .log file.

The application is currently logging correctly to `log/development.log`, but the deployed application itself is not logging anything. It hasn't even made a `log/production.log` file.

The only thing that is different in my `config/production.rb` file is:

```
config.log_level = :info
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to try?

UPDATE: I have now tried to simply do a File.open(filename, 'w') within production and development. It will work in dev, but not in production which leads me to think that perhaps the production docker image simply does not have access to writing to a file.

Ruby Version: 2.3.1p112

Rails Version: 5.0.0

Docker Version: 1.12.6

Answer (score -3):

I have found out what was going wrong! The `/log` folder was not being mounted correctly to the Docker image, so I needed to fix that. Also, the gem [`rails_12factor`](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) was causing the logger to write to stdout rather than to the default file location. Changing both of these seems to have fixed the issue.

Thanks for anyone who looked at this!

Comment: that was not helpful. please write how you fixed it.